# Multiplying strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I "multiply" a string (in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c)

In Python I can do this:

```
>>> i = 3
>>> 'hello' * i
'hellohellohello'
```

**How can I multiply strings in C# similarly to in Python?**  I could easily do it in a for loop but that gets tedious and non-expressive.

Ultimately I'm writing out to console recursively with an indented level being incremented with each call.

```
parent
    child
    child
    child
        grandchild
```

And it'd be easiest to just do `"\t" * indent`.

Comment: Write an extension method, so you can do "hello".times(5). (I'd do it in an answer if I knew C#).

Comment: Unless C# allows operator overloading; does it?

Comment: @mmyers adding behavior to default classes is considered harmful

Comment: @Eric: Considered harmful by who? It can be extremely useful. I would have no problem with this.

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c/532912#532912

Comment: @Eric: the visibility of an extension method is limited to the declaring namespace of that method, not to all users of the extended type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an extension method for it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c/532912#532912).

```
public static string Multiply(this string source, int multiplier)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(multiplier * source.Length);
   for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
   {
       sb.Append(source);
   }

   return sb.ToString();
}

string s = "</li></ul>".Multiply(10);
```

Comment: I'd make multiplier a uint to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Very slick. I'm definitely going to start using this.

Comment: If multiplier is negative an exception will be thrown on creating the StringBuilder and the loop wouldn't even run in any case ...

Comment: Using a StringBuilder for this is probably overkill, unless the multiplier is generally very large (as in thousands).

Comment: From my own testing, using a StringBuilder where you specify the buffer size (as here) breaks even in speed with about 3-4 concatenations.

Answer (score 14):

If you just need a single character you can do:

```
new string('\t', i)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c) for more info.

Comment: This works for my immediate problem so I guess it's the accepted answer.  In general though this wouldn't work. :)

Comment: I really think the extension method Shane Fulmer posted is a better solution. I'd mark his response as the answer IMHO.

Comment: @Chris, how do I decide then between the better answer for my specific problem that led to this question and a better, more general answer?

Comment: I think Shane Fulmer's answer is a more elegant solution to your specific problem. After you implement it just do "\t".Multiply(i). Not saying I don't appreciate the points :), just think his solution is superior.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how I do it...

```
string value = new string(' ',5).Replace(" ","Apple");
```

Comment: I made some simple performance tests and found this to be faster than the `StringBuilder` or `string.Join` version.

Comment: This solution just made my day!

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing built-in to the BCL to do this, but a bit of LINQ can accomplish the task easily enough:

```
var multiplied = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("hello", 5).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int indent = 5;
string s = new string('\t', indent);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is the following - but it's not that nice.

```
 String.Join(String.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat("hello", 3).ToArray())
```

**UPDATE**

Ahhhh ... I remeber ... for chars ...

```
 new String('x', 3)
```

Comment: Identical to mine. It's not the most elegant, but at least it's simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

how about with a linq aggregate...

```
var combined = Enumerable.Repeat("hello", 5).Aggregate("", (agg, current) => agg + current);
```

Comment: var combined = Enumerable.Repeat("hello", 5).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (agg, current) => agg.Append(current)).ToString();

Answer (score 0):

There is no such statement in C#; your best bet is probably your own MultiplyString() function.

Answer (score 0):

Per mmyers:

```
public static string times(this string str, int count)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i=0; i<count; i++) 
  {
    sb.Append(str);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's only one character that you want to repeat, there is a String constructor that you can use:

```
string indentation = new String('\t', indent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can extend System.String with an operator overload, but you could make a string wrapper class to do it.

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public StringWrapper()
    {
        this.Value = string.Empty;
    }

    public StringWrapper(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static StringWrapper operator *(StringWrapper wrapper,
                                           int timesToRepeat)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < timesToRepeat; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(wrapper.Value);
        }

        return new StringWrapper(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then call it like...

```
var helloTimesThree = new StringWrapper("hello") * 3;
```

And get the value from...

```
helloTimesThree.Value;
```

Of course, the sane thing to do would be to have your function track and pass in the current depth and dump tabs out in a for loop based off of that.

Answer (score -1):

if u need string 3 times just do

```
string x = "hello";

string combined = x + x + x;
```

Comment: Doesn't scale very nicely does it...