# Sequence multiplication in c#

Tags: c#, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to return a string repeated X number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times)

In Python you can multiply sequences like this

```
fivespaces= ' ' * 5
```

Is there any built-in equivalent for this in C#? (without operator overloads or class extensions)

Comment: @AhmadMageed -- I'm not sure that I agree that this is a duplicate.  As I see it, strings are just an example.  python has other sequence types too (like a list):  `five_spaces_in_a_list = [' ']*5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just a string then you can return multiples by passing in a count to `string()`

`var fivespaces = new string(" ", 5);`

In the case where you want a collection of something else like a custom type, you can use `Enumerable.Repeat` to get a collection:

`var items = Enumerable.Repeat(new SomeModel(), 5);`

Comment: thanks, worked with single quotes :)

Comment: The 2nd example would also be useful if someone wanted to use sequence multiplication on an Array/List so thanks.

Comment: I don't agree with the close as duplicate. The other thread only covers string concatenation. The following would also count as a sequence multiplcation. s=[1,2,3,4,5] *5;

Comment: The `String` constructor example doesn't compile. The only `String` constructor overload that repeats a value takes a single `char` (inside single quotes, not doubles as in the answer). There is no overload taking and repeating a `string`.