# repeat string with LINQ/extensions methods

Tags: c#-4.0

Just a curiosity I was investigating.

The matter: simply repeating (multiplying, someone would say) a string/character **n** times.
I know there is **Enumerable.Repeat** for this aim, but I was trying to do this without it.
**LINQ** in this case seems pretty useless, because in a **query** like

```
from X in "s" select X
```

the **string** "s" is being explored and so X is a **char**. The same is with **extension methods**, because for example "s".**Aggregate**(blablabla) would again work on just the character 's', not the string itself. For repeating the string something "external" would be needed, so I thought **lambdas** and **delegates**, but it can't be done without declaring a variable to assign the delegate/lambda expression to.
So something like defining a function and calling it inline:

```
( (a)=>{return " "+a;} )("a");
```

or

```
delegate(string a){return " "+a}(" ");
```

would give a "without name" error (and so **no recursion**, AFAIK, even by passing a possible lambda/delegate as a **parameter**), and in the end couldn't even be created by C# because of its limitations.
It could be that I'm watching this thing from the wrong perspective. Any ideas?
This is just an experiment, I don't care about performances, about memory use... Just that it is one line and sort of autonomous. Maybe one could do something with Copy/CopyTo, or casting it to some other collection, I don't know. **Reflection** is accepted too.

Comment: almost; I'd like to avoid enumerable.repeat

Comment: Did you read the answer to that post? It uses the string constructor, not `Enumerable.Repeat`.

Comment: it repeats a character, ok, but a string

Comment: I've added an answer below that will repeat strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to repeat a string, rather than a character, a simple way would be to use the [`StringBuilder.Insert` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62eb5xsf.aspx), which takes an insertion index and a count for the number of repetitions to use:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Insert(0, "hi!", 5);
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Otherwise, to repeat a single character, use the string constructor as I've mentioned in the comments for the [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754700/59111). For example:

```
string result = new String('-', 5); // -----
```

For the sake of completeness, it's worth noting that `StringBuilder` provides an [overloaded `Append` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e.aspx) that can repeat a character, but has no such overload for strings (which is where the `Insert` method comes in). I would prefer the string constructor to the `StringBuilder` if that's all I was interested in doing. However, if I was already working with a `StringBuilder`, it might make sense to use the `Append` method to benefit from some chaining. Here's a contrived example to demonstrate:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("This item is ");
sb.Insert(sb.Length, "very ", 2) // insert at the end to append
  .Append('*', 3)
  .Append("special")
  .Append('*', 3);
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // This item is very very ***special***
```

Answer (score 10):

To repeat a character n-times you would not use `Enumerable.Repeat` but just [this string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx):

```
string str = new string('X', 10);
```

To repeat a string i don't know anything better than using `string.Join` and `Enumerable.Repeat`

```
string foo = "Foo";
string str = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(foo, 10));
```

edit: you could use `string.Concat` instead if you need no separator:

```
string str = string.Concat( Enumerable.Repeat(foo, 10) );
```

Comment: I didn't see that, useful; do you know something for repeating a string, even?

Comment: saw it; better late than never