# Is there a LINQ-way to append the same character n-times to a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a string repeating the same seqeuence n-times.

How I do this:

```
var sequence = "\t";
var indent = string.Empty;   

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    indent += sequence;
}
```

Is there a neat LINQ equivalent to accomplish the same result?

Comment: [repeat string with LINQ/extensions methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13864493/150605) is very similar but seeks to repeat `string`s, not `char`s.  [Best way to repeat a character in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411752/150605) is identical as far as seeking to create a `string` of tab characters, and though it isn't restricted to LINQ, does contain many LINQ/`Enumerable` answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Repeat` in `String.Concat`:

```
string intend = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(sequence, n));
```

If you just want to repeat a single character you should prefer the `String`-constructor:

```
string intend = new String('\t', n);
```

Comment: @boop Not relevant for your sample code, but if you are using a StringBuilder, there is also a method .Append('\t', n).

Comment: I recommend `string.Join(sequence, new string[n + 1])` to avoid the StringBuilder overhead