# Show number of stars instead of the number

Tags: c#, rating-system

I am making i site where people can make reviews of movies and when they make the review they need to put a rating to a movie, in a number of 1 to 5.

But when it print out on another page I want to print out stars insted of the number 3 for exemple.

For now I got this code:

```
StringBuilder movielistSB = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var moviereview in movielistSB)
            {
                filmanmeldelserlisteSB.AppendFormat(
                    "<div id='moviereview'><artitcle><h3>{0}</h3>" + 
                    "<table><tr><td>ID:</td><td>{1}</td></tr>" + 
                    "<tr><td>Anmeldelse:</td><td>{2}</td></tr>" + 
                    "<tr><td>Rating:</td><td>{3}</td></tr></table></article></div>",
                    (string)moviereview.Element("title"),
                    (string)moviereview.Element("id"),
                    (string)moviereview.Element("review"),
                    (string)moviereview.Element("rating")
                );
```

And for the (string)moviereview.Element("rating") I want to print out for exempel 3 stars when a user has given the movie a rating of 3.

I tried to run a for loop, but I could not figur out how to get that to work. And I've tried to Google for a solution, but anyhow I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:
For now I got this:

```
String star = @"<img src=""../images/star.png""/>";

    if (moviereviewlist.Count() > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder moviereviewlistSB = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var moviereview in moviereviewlist)
        {
            filmanmeldelserlisteSB.AppendFormat(
                "<div id='moviereview'><artitcle><h3>{0}</h3>" + 
                "<table><tr><td>ID:</td><td>{1}</td></tr>" + 
                "<tr><td>Review:</td><td>{2}</td></tr>" + 
                "<tr><td>Rating:</td><td>{3}</td></tr></table></article></div>",
                (string)moviereview.Element("tittel"),
                (string)moviereview.Element("id"),
                (string)moviereview.Element("anmeldelse"),
                star.RepeatString((int)moviereview.Element("rating"))
            );
```

and this

```
    public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RepeatString(this string input, int count)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.Length * count);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            builder.Append(input);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I had to parse the `(int)filmanmeldelse.Element("rating")' to an int. But for somehow I can't get a image on the site. Its only blank and I have tried different ways, but It will not get a value to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder movielistSB = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var moviereview in movielistSB)
{
    filmanmeldelserlisteSB.AppendFormat(
            "<div id='moviereview'><artitcle><h3>{0}</h3>" + 
            "<table><tr><td>ID:</td><td>{1}</td></tr>" + 
            "<tr><td>Anmeldelse:</td><td>{2}</td></tr>" + 
            "<tr><td>Rating:</td><td>{3}</td></tr></table></article></div>",
            (string)moviereview.Element("title"),
            (string)moviereview.Element("id"),
            (string)moviereview.Element("review"),
            new String('*', moviereview.Element("rating"))
        );
```

This works, because `String` has a constructor that takes a Character to repeat, and a number of times to repeat it.

So the code:

```
new String('X', 5);
```

would result in the string `"XXXXX"` (five X's in a row)

---

**EDIT** Poster asks if something similar can be used to insert Image-Links.

*Reply:* No.  This String method repeats *a single character*, not a block of text.
If you want to repeat a block of text, you'll want something like:

```
String starImage = @"<img src=""StarImage.jpg""/>";

filmanmeldelserlisteSB.AppendFormat(
            "<div id='moviereview'><artitcle><h3>{0}</h3>" + 
            "<table><tr><td>ID:</td><td>{1}</td></tr>" + 
            "<tr><td>Anmeldelse:</td><td>{2}</td></tr>" + 
            "<tr><td>Rating:</td><td>{3}</td></tr></table></article></div>",
            (string)moviereview.Element("title"),
            (string)moviereview.Element("id"),
            (string)moviereview.Element("review"),
            starImage.RepeatString(movieReview.Element("rating"))
        );
```

But you'll have to write your own `RepeatString` method.
A guide to doing that can be found on [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times)

---

**EDIT #2**

Writing an extension method is not hard.
I would put this class somewhere in your project's namespace.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RepeatString(this string input, int count)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.Length * count);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            builder.Append(input);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Geesh... you really can't debug, can you?**

You have an extra **!** in this code:

```
public static string RepeatString(this string input, int count)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))  // <-- Extra !
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Its a pretty simple statement!  
*"If the string is Null or Empty, return an Empty string"*
But you have it backwards, so it effectively says:
*"If the string has text in it, return an Empty string"*.
That makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I want to use a image of a star instead of '*', can I just replace the '*'?

Comment: Hm, tried for some hours to figur this out now, but I really can't understand where I should write the RepeatString method and how. Tried the different methods showed in the link you gave, but can't figur out how to really do it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
(string)moviereview.Element("rating")
```

Use:

```
new string('*', int.Parse((string)moviereview.Element("rating")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If I want to use a image of a star instead of *, can I just insert img src?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this code to work:

```
public static string Multiply(this string source, int multiplier)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(multiplier * source.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(source);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks for the help guys!