# C# Linq to XML - Reviews website with Dropdownlist rating with image

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, linq-to-xml, rating

So,i have this little project im working on. Things are in Norwegain, so ill try to explain a bit.

Im making a website where i can read and add movie reviews. I have one aspx site called 'Movie reviews'which display's both Title, Review and rating (from 0-5 in a dropdownlist), and another aspx site called 'Add new movie reviews' where i can CRUD title, review and rating(dropdownlist) with the moviereviews.xml file.

Movie = film

Review = anmeldelse

Title = tittel

```
<movies>
  <movie>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Iron Man</title>
    <review>Bla bla bla...</review>
    <rating>2</rating>
  </movie>
</movies>
```

a snippet of the working code behind in the 'Add new movie reviews' site:

```
 protected void lagreBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filePath = Server.MapPath("/xml/filmanmeldelser.xml");

    XElement anmeldelserXML = XElement.Load(filePath);

    anmeldelserXML.Add(
        new XElement("film",
            new XElement("id",hentNyUnikId()),
            new XElement("tittel", tittelTxt.Text),
            new XElement("anmeldelse", anmeldelseTxt.Text),
            new XElement("rating", rangeringDropDownList.SelectedValue)
            )

        );
    anmeldelserXML.Save(filePath);
```

and another snippet of code behind in the 'Movie reviews' site:

```
protected string hentFilePath(string filnavn)
    {
        String filePath = Server.MapPath("../xml/" + filnavn);//OR ("/xml/" + filnavn)

        return Server.MapPath("../xml/" + filnavn);//OR ("/xml/" + filnavn)
    }

protected void visFilmanmeldelseListe()
{
    String filePath = Server.MapPath("/xml/filmanmeldelser.xml");

    XElement anmeldelserXML = XElement.Load(filePath);

    var filmeanmeldelseListe = from filmer in anmeldelserXML.Descendants("film")
                                  select filmer;

        if(filmeanmeldelseListe.Count() > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder filmanmeldelseListeSB = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var film in filmeanmeldelseListe)
            {
                filmanmeldelseListeSB.AppendFormat(
                    "<article><h1>{0}</h1><p>Anmeldelse: {1}</p><p>Rangering: {2}</p></article>",
                        (string)film.Element("tittel"),
                        (string)film.Element("anmeldelse"),
                        (string)film.Element("rating")
                    );
            }
            filmanmeldelseListeLiteral.Text = filmanmeldelseListeSB.ToString();
        }
```

Now, this works great...

But, (Wooah! A wild problem appeared!). Instead of numbers, showing Iron Man with a rating of 5 from the dropdownlist, i would instead like to show a star-image X times compared to the dropdownlist value chosen, like a "normal" rating control when you rate movies n such. I have this image in a file called 'pictures' within the website project.

Example: Giving a rating of 5, will show 5 stars. Gving a rating of 2, shows 2 stars.

Ive been trying for a couple of days now, and i cant seem to get my head around it...
Does anyone have any good tips, tricks or solutions to get me unstuck on this problem?:)

Any help would be absolutely great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617511/show-number-of-stars-instead-of-the-number/22617583#22617583

Comment: are you the same person, or working on the same assignment? both Norway I notice...

Comment: Actually working on the same assignement:) Know the guy, just didnt know he pasted a question on the site. Thanks for the link man!

Comment: He's way ahead of you :P - good luck