# For loop Hash character pattern

Tags: c#, for-loop

Hi i am new to programming and i currently have this code:

```
   namespace Patterns
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)//'rows'
            {
                for (int h = 1; h <= 9 - (i*2)+1; h++)
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n" );

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces this output:

```
########
######
####
##
```

the number of hashes is correct as i am going from 8, 6, 4, 2 but i need to add an extra space every time i go onto a new line. How do i make it so the output is as follows?

```
########
 ######
  ####
   ##
```

Thanks,
Umer

Comment: Another loop printing the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

From your code you could modify it to do the following in the inner for loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
  Console.Write(" ");
}
for (int h = 1; h <= 9 - (i*2)+1; h++) {
  Console.Write("#");
}
Console.WriteLine("\n" );
```

As a note you should probably use StringBuilder to do this as I believe it is quite inefficient to constantly call Console.WriteLine.

The code could be modified further:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
    sb.append(" ");
  }
  for (int h = 1; h <= 9 - (i*2)+1; h++) {
    sb.append("#");
  }
  sb.append("\n" );
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce variables, start your rows at 0 and [repeat the string for each row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times).

This can also be applied to the string printing the hashes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    int rows = 4;
    int columns = 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {       
        // Print a string with `i` spaces.
        Console.Write(new String(' ', i));

        int hashes = columns - ((i + 1) * 2) + 1;
        Console.Write(new String('#', hashes));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just add space in front of your hash characters.

```
######## Row 1 (i=1), 0 Space
 ######  Row 2 (i=2), 1 Space
  ####   Row 3 (i=3), 2 Spaces
   ##    Row 4 (i=4), 3 Spaces
```

In this case, you need "i-1" spaces for each rows. (Actually, it's (8 - charater count) / 2) and character count was 9 - (i*2) + 1, so ( 8 - 9 + i * 2 - 1 ) / 2 = (i * 2 - 2) / 2 = i - 1 )
So just make loop to add spaces before print hash chracters.

```
 namespace Patterns
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)//'rows'
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i -1; j++) {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for (int h = 1; h <= 9 - (i*2)+1; h++)
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n" );

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)//'rows'
        {
            for (int h = 1; h <= 9 - (i*2)+1; h++)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n" );
            for (int y = i; y > 0; y--)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");    
            }

        }
```