# Regex for replacing multiple white spaces with multiple &nbsp;

Tags: c#, regex

I've seen multiple examples of replacing whitespaces with single space/`&nbsp;`, but I want to replace every space that has two or more white spaces with equal `&nbsp;`

```
Regex.Replace(theString, @"[\s+]{2,}", "&nbsp;");
```

This replace works, but if it is for example two whitespaces it inserts one `&nbsp;` and I understand that.

How can I replace it with two `&nbsp;` or more if the counts is over two?

String:

```
This text   contains    multiple whitespaces
```

Wanted result:
`This&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;contains&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;multiple&nbsp;whitespaces`

Is this possible with Regex.Replace or do I need to loop each whitespace and replace it?

Comment: It appears that your input string and wanted result would describe the problem as "replace every whitespace with `&nbsp;`" yet your problem description is (parahprasing) "replace every whitespace sequence longer than two with `&nbsp;` sequence of equal length"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a match evaluator to build the custom replacement:

```
var s = " 1  2   3    4 ";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s{2,}", m =>
    string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&nbsp;", m.Length)));
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => ' 1&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4 '
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/bfhvLv)

Here, `\s{2,}` matches 2 or more whitespaces, the match is assigned to `m` inside the match evaluator, and `string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&nbsp;", m.Length))` builds a string that consists of `&nbsp;` substrings of match length times (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754630/3832970)).