# Optimal Environment.Newline in interpolated string

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I wanted to insert multiple new lines in a string so I used an interpolated string as my choice of a format mechanism which should be pretty fast.

Example:

`string mystring = $"one line{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}another line{Environment.NewLine}end";`

Now that works but how can I better insert multiple `Environment.Newline` in an interpolated string; for example if I wanted 15 this gets cumbersome.

I am aware of `string.Replace(`, `string.Format()`, and concatenation `Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine` as well as literal string `@"stuff"` with blank lines however is not the question (an alternative) but rather how to insert multiples such my fake example of

`string mystring = $"one line{Environment.NewLine(3)}another line{Environment.NewLine}end text";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but you can call a method from within an interpolated string.  The method can return a specified number of new lines.

```
private string NewLines(int lines)
{           
 return new StringBuilder().Insert(0,$"{Environment.NewLine}, lines").ToString();
}
```

Then just call

```
string mystring = $"one line{NewLines(3)}another line{NewLines(1)}end text";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple helper method to get a repeated string, and then call that:

```
static string Repeat(string input, int count)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) result.Append(input);
    return result.ToString();
}

string mystring = 
    $"one line{Repeat(Environment.NewLine, 3)}another line{Environment.NewLine}end";
```

And if you don't want to explicitly call another function, you could write an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Repeat(this string input, int count)
    {
        if (input == null) return null;
        if (count < 1) return string.Empty;
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) result.Append(input);
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then the syntax is simpler:

```
string mystring = 
    $"one line{Environment.NewLine.Repeat(3)}another line{Environment.NewLine}end";
```

Comment: Noted in question I know about this option, thanks

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: One reason is to optimize for a highly performance driven application thus creating a `StringBuilder` or doing a loop, calling  a custom method etc. is/was not an option considered.  Thanks for posting however as it may fit someone else's circumstance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any solution that takes a string and a count is going to use a loop behind the scenes. I.e. [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Repeat.cs), and [`StringBuilder.Insert`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,4fc7620ab6118309). For performance, I guess you want something that resolves at compile time. Not sure about that one.

Answer (score 2):

Linq can do this:

```
var fifteenNewlines = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Environment.NewLine, 15));
```

Comment: I see this answer was [already given in a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816447/22437).