# In C# how do you output a string x times?

Tags: c#, string

In Python, you can write `2*'hello'` in the shell and the IDLE will output `'hellohello'`.   Is there a way to output 'multiples' of a string in C# to do the same thing?

Comment: just use a for loop, haven't heard of it beeing as simple as in python

Comment: Unfortunately you can do it e.g. in foreach loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an easy way to return a string repeated X number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built-in function to repeat a string or char in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?view=net-5.0)

> Generates a sequence that contains one repeated value.

Then [`String.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-5.0)

> Concatenates one or more instances of String, or the String
> representations of the values of one or more instances of Object.

**Example**

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("hello",3)));
```

**Output**

```
hellohellohello
```