# Is there a built-in function to repeat a string or char in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Is there a function in C# that returns *x* times of a given char or string? Or must I code it myself?

Comment: this is not an exact duplicate:  this is a way to do it.  Dim line As String = New [String]("-"c, 100)

Comment: Well, better late than never. I voted for re-opening this as it is **not** a duplicate of linked possible duplicate. [Best way to repeat a character in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp) does **not** cover repeating strings but only characters!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I "multiply" a string (in C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to return a string repeated X number of times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("ab", 2));
```

Returns

```
"abab"
```

And

```
string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat('a', 2))
```

Returns

```
"aa"
```

Comment: slightly more correct answers below -- use the native 'join' for characters [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19248082/1037948), or `string.Concat` for strings [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15390834/1037948)

Comment: If code already uses Linq, use `string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("ab", 2).ToArray());`

Comment: For chars as mentioned new string(char ch, int count) is better. An improvement of this could be to use Concat.

Answer (score 61):

```
string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("ab", 2));
```

returns

> "abab"

Comment: If code already uses Linq, use `string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("ab", 2).ToArray());`

Answer (score 32):

For strings you should indeed use Kirk's solution:

```
string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("ab", 2));
```

However for chars you might as well use the built-in (more efficient) string constructor:

```
new string('a', 2); // returns aa
```

Comment: Deserved 1 point for Mentioning the proper way to repeat Character. You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp too. Good Luck.

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is the built in string function:

```
 Strings.StrDup(2, "a")
```

Comment: Not the best, since you need to reference and import Microsoft.VisualBasic.

Comment: for me, it is the best because I am using VB in a project!

Answer (score 5):

```
new String('*', 5)
```

See [Rosetta Code](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#C.23).

Comment: I think this is only for char

Comment: yes you right it is only for char duplication