# Is there built-in method to add character multiple times to a string?

Tags: c#, string, for-loop

Is there a built-in function or more efficient way to add character to a string X number of times?

for example the following code will add '0' character 5 times to the string:

```
int count = 5;
char someChar = '0';
string myString = "SomeString";

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    myString = someChar + myString;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in function to repeat string or char in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115064/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-repeat-string-or-char-in-net)

Comment: @Sajeetharan in my case using `PadRight()` or `PadLeft()` is more efficient and does exactly what I need with minimal overhead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to repeat a character in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411752/best-way-to-repeat-a-character-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `PadLeft()` or `PadRight()`

An example for `PadRight()`:

```
int count = 5;
char someChar = '0';
string myString = "SomeString";

myString = myString.PadRight(count + myString.Length, someChar);

// output -> "SomeString00000"
```

Remember the first parameter of either method is the **total** string length required hence why I am adding count to the original string length.

Likewise if you want to append the character at the start of the string use `PadLeft()`

```
myString = myString.PadLeft(count + myString.Length, someChar);

// output -> "00000SomeString"
```

Comment: OP is padding left though

Comment: @UlfKristiansen I could have sworn that character was being added at the end of the string when I first read the question! Have updated with both options - thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it as:

```
string line = "abc";
line = "abc" + new String('X', 5);
//line == abcXXXXX
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("0", 5));
```

will return

"00000"

Refered from :[Is there a built-in function to repeat string or char in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115064/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-repeat-string-or-char-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here, You can use [`PadRight()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [`PadLeft()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
int count = 5;
char someChar = '0';
string myString = "SomeString";
var stringLength = myString.Length;

var newPaddedStringRight = myString.PadRight(stringLength  + count, '0'); 
//will give SomeString00000
var newPaddedStringLeft = myString.PadLeft(stringLength  + count, '0'); 
//will give 00000SomeString
```

Remember, a string is *Immutable*, so you'll need to assign the result to a new string.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky, I updated...I was just showing how to use the function.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use StringBuilder.  As the string size increases the += incurs a cost on array copy.