# How to repeat a set of characters

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'd like to repeat a set of characters multiple times.  I know how to do it with a single character:

```
string line = new string('x', 10);
```

But what I'd like would be something more like this:

```
string line = new string("-.", 10);
```

which would result in: -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.

I know the string constructor can't do it, but is there some other way within the BCL? Other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I “multiply” a string (in C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/532892/588306)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to return a string repeated X number of times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A slight variation on the answer by [Bala R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273200/bala-r)

```
var s = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("-.", 10));
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution for what I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

```
var result = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("-.", 10));
```

Comment: Have never seen the Enumerable class. Awesome +1

Comment: @RyanBennett, you mean you never used LINQ? :)

Comment: Not like that - not sure how I was able to go three years and overlook an entire class...

Comment: Thanks! I also didn't know about the Enumerable class. Very nice.

Answer (score 9):

```
string line = new String('x', 10).Replace("x", "-.");
```

Comment: Nice way, if you can not access the Enumerable class (like in WinWrapBasic)