# Multiplier operation string in C#

Tags: c#, mono

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I “multiply” a string (in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c)

I want to achieve this

```
string a = "Hello";
Console.Write (a * 10);
```

I want it to print out :

```
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
```

I know in python I can just do

```
a = "hello"
print a * 10
```

but how do I do this in C# ?

Comment: There's a veritable cornucopia of ways to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c

Comment: Instead of editing your question title to indicate that it has been solved, please [mark one of the answers as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/135887) using the built-in user interface.  If none of the existing answers actually solved the problem, please add your own answer detailing the solution, then mark *that* answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string repeated = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat("Hello", 10));
```