# How to print the same character many times with Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, printing, console.writeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to return a string repeated X number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754582/is-there-an-easy-way-to-return-a-string-repeated-x-number-of-times)

If I want to display a dot 10 times in Python, I could either use this:

```
print ".........."
```

or this

```
print "." * 10
```

How do I use the second method in C#? I tried variations of:

```
Console.WriteLine("."*10);
```

but none of them worked. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not properly formatting my code and thanks for the correction.

Comment: plz, see here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c/532912#532912

Comment: Repeating a character and repeating the string aren't the same. Voting to reopen the question. Coincidentally [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3754700/465053) in the thread used to mark this question as duplicate should have been in this thread instead.

Comment: Now I found that this post is a possible duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411752/465053) instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`string` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(new string('.', 10));
```

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated
>   by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. And just a quick general question. I am new to StackOverflow. If I see that several people have given correct answers and all of them are equally correct and exhaustive, on what basis do I mark a particular answer as best answer?

Comment: For Python 3: 
print('.' * 10)

Answer (score 4):

I would say the most straight forward answer is to use a `for` loop. This uses less storage.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Console.Write('.');
Console.WriteLine();
```

But you can also allocate a string that contains the repeated characters. This involves less typing and is almost certainly faster.

```
Console.WriteLine(new String('.', 10));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the 'string' constructors, like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string('.', 10));
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
string print = "";
for(int i = 0; i< 10 ; i++)
{
print = print + ".";
} 
Console.WriteLine(print);
```