# How to display a string x number of times on one line C#

Tags: c#, string, while-loop

I need to have a user enter a number between 1 - 80 and have it print however many * the number is I have managed to get it to print the correct number of * just not on one line.

Comment: Show your code, please. And normally you would use a loop.

Comment: `string oneLine = new string('*', number);`?

Comment: Well I just managed to get it on one line I was using Console.Writeline where Console.Write fixed it. Now I just need to get the loop to circle back.                                                          
     while (1 <= num & num <= 80) // if the number is between 1 & 80 it passses { while (counter != num) { Console.Write("*",num); //outputs the number of * counter++ // Output your line of * per the directions }

Comment: You should ask a new question, really. SO won't run out of question IDs any time soon! :) Not really sure what circle back means - you want to return the cursor to the start of the line for when you next print? Use a single call to `Console.WriteLine()`. You want counter to be 1 again? Just set it to 1 after the loop

Comment: Does this answer your question [Can I “multiply” a string (in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c) and [How to print the same character many times with Console.WriteLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456665/how-to-print-the-same-character-many-times-with-console-writeline)

Answer (score 2):

> I have managed to get it to print the correct number of * just not on one line.

I suspect you've used `Console.WriteLine`

Use `Console.Write` instead

---

Always (always) post the code you've written, that is malfunctioning, so we can see it

Comment: Sorry first question I asked and you were correct

Answer (score 0):

here is an exemple of printing ***** in one line. In this exemple, I stop the loop when *i* is not <5 but you can replace 5 with a number you want.

```cs
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("*");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this assignment required a while loop with a nested while loop in that

Comment: @crazy4dev *i stop the loop when i is not <5* needs some revision to the wording

Answer (score -1):

For an easy one liner

```
var starString = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", number));
```

alternatively if you need a loop for whatever reason

```
string starString = "";
for(var i = 0; i< number;i++)
     starString += "*";
```

Comment: 100 string concatenations should really use a string builder.. also see Ahmed's comment about using the string constructor designed for this