# Outputting a _ for each letter of a string in an array (hangman)

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
    public void Dashes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SelectedWord.Length; i++)
            console.WriteLine("_");

    }
```

this is the only thing i can think of and whenever I go to run it puts it on all separate lines when I want it on 1 line

Comment: Thanks all i needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Dashes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SelectedWord.Length; i++)
        console.Write("_");

}
```

Thanks to @Grant Winney

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < SelectedWord.Length; i++)
            {
                output += "_";
            }
            console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Why not just simply use Console.Write instead of Console.WriteLine and save all the immutable concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

The console,writeline prints starts a new line everytime its called in your loop.

```
public void Dashes()
    {
        string dashes ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < SelectedWord.Length; i++)
            dashes +="_";
        console.WriteLine(dashes);

    }
```

Comment: Why not just simply use Console.Write instead of Console.WriteLine and save all the immutable concatenation?

Comment: You would still need a writeline().  The person asking this question is a novice and don't make things more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also ditch the loop entirely if running .NET 4 or above and use the following single line (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3297622/1813169)):

```
console.WriteLine(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("_", SelectedWord.Length)));
```